# Scaling not as smooth in 3.0 as in 2.x

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-animation, core-graphics

I have a `CATiledLayer` backed `UIView` that is added to `UIScrollView` and it is returned as view to be scaled in response to `-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` delegate method.

Now the problem is that scaling on a scale falling between the 2x steps provided by `CATiledLayer` (like for example 1.333) results in very pixelated image when I compile and test against 3.0 SDK. In 2.2.1 the scaling is much smoother.

I tried to set layer's `minificationFilter` to `kCAFilterTrilinear`, but that resulted in a way too blurry image.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

After some playing, I discovered that only the 2.x **Simulator** smoothens the scaled image. On the real device with 2.x SDK, the scaling is the same as on 3.0.

Comment: They tell you this on one of the first pages of their dev documentation. Common sense as well.

Comment: The only source of confusion is that only 3.0 correctly simulates the device behavior, while 2.x uses obviously some other algorithm... Where exactly in the docs did you find a pointer to this?